# Proof for inequality with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

If $a,b,c$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}$ show that

$$ac+bd \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2 +d^2}$$

Let's use $z=a+bi$ and $g=c+di$ so $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $|g|=\sqrt{c^2 +d^2}$. So the equation is something like this

$$\operatorname{Re}(z)\operatorname{Re}(g)+\operatorname{Im}(z)\operatorname{Im}(g)\leq|z||g|$$

Well for one the right hand side can't be negative and the left hand side can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if you let $z=a+bi$ and $g=c-di$ you'd have the same $|z|$ and $|g|$, but $ac+bd = \mathrm{Re}(zg)$. Then it is obvious that $\mathrm{Re}(zg)\leq |zg|= |z|\cdot |g|$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in 2 dimensions; i.e. for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $$\langle x,y \rangle \leq \| x \| \|y \|,$$
where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is the standard cartesian inner product and $\| \cdot  \|$ the standard Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. For the proof, use $a+bi$ and $d+ci$ together with $\mathrm{Im}z\leq|z|$.